# SQLite in Android - No Such Table

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm new to Android programming and I'm trying to access my database. I put it in my project root directory, the database file is called "db".

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {  

// Database Version  
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;  
// Database Name  
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db";  

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {  
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);  
}  

@Override  
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {  
}  

@Override  
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {  
}  

public Object[] getData(int id) {  
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();  
    Cursor cursor = db.query("TESTE",         // <<<<<<<<<<<< Error  
            new String[] { "FI1, FI2, FI3" },  
            " ID_FI1 = ?",  
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null,  
            null);  
    if (cursor != null) {  
        cursor.moveToFirst();  
    }  
    return data;  
}
```

}

I opened the database with the sqlite browser and there is indeed a table with the name "TESTE" and those fields.

Comment: post stacktrace. also, there is nothing in your onCreate, how do you create the db?

Comment: Post the table creation routine

Comment: I'm not in front of a compiler right now (I'll be in a few mins) so I can't post the stacktrace. About the onCreate according to the documentation the onCreate is called when I'm creating a database and since I already have a database with the table and the data in it I didn't put anything there.

Comment: The name is not wrong. I copy pasted from the database just to be 100% sure about it. The database is not in the asset folder, it's in the root (altho I copied the database file there just to be safe).

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to store the database? When you use DDMS to browse the phone or emulator, it should be somewhere similar to data/data/package.name/databases.

Comment: Yes there is a "db" file in my DDMS in the following directory: "data/data/com.example/databases".

Comment: Is your package named `com.example`? does the `"db" file in my DDMS` have the correct name?

Comment: Yes and yes. I even renamed the database and tried again and still the same error.